# Using ffmpeg command in system() always show "Operation not permitted"?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a command `ffmpeg -i sample.bmp -vf format=rgb24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y tmp.yuv`

If i run it in terminal, it always works fine with output file, but if I run with c++:

```
std::string cmd = "ffmpeg -i sample.bmp -vf format=rgb24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y tmp.yuv";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

The output file simply won't be generated and shows `"sample.bmp: Operation not permitted"`

I have already given `chmod 777` to my `sample.bmp` file and path is correct.

Comment: Is the working directory the same? Can you open the `sample.bmp` for reading using `fopen` (just to verify)?

Comment: Try using full path instead of relative path to check if it's an issue of working directory or not.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson It works! Thanks!! But why? system() has some limit of the directory range?

Comment: I put sample.bmp in the same directory with my program and it works!

Comment: @Michael because the executable's working directory may not be the expected one. Check your build environment and specs.